# Key, Value pair with multiples pairs on a line; sed

Tags: bash, perl, sed

Suppose I have a file with multiple key, value pairs on a line:

```
$ cat test.txt
fruit: 23 oranges 55 bananas 3 peaches
candy: 16 m&m's 5 ju_ju_beans
```

With Perl, it is trivial to capture multiple key, value pairs of unknown number on each line:

```
$ perl -lane 'print "$1" while m/(\d+\s+\S+)/g' /tmp/test.txt
23 oranges
55 bananas
3 peaches
16 m&m's
5 ju_ju_beans
```

Is this possible to do with sed?

I have tried:

```
$ sed -E -n 's/(\d+\s+\S+)/$1\n/g; p' /tmp/test.txt
fruit: 23 oranges 55 bananas 3 peaches
candy: 16 m&m's 5 ju_ju_beans
```

But that just prints the entire line. Is it possible (in some what that my Google foo fails me) to just print one key, value pair match per line?

Comment: May I ask -- why the downvote? Is there something wrong with this question? I honestly try and only ask questions that are not obvious and answers that are usefull. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Have added a GNU `awk` variant using `regex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grep can do it alone:

```
# perl compatible regex
grep -oP '\d+\s+\S+'
# vanilla basic regex
grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+[[:blank:]]\+[^[:blank:]]\+' file
```

Comment: `grep -oE '\d+\s+\S+'` on OS X / BSD methinks

Answer (score 5):

`sed` does not recognize PCRE and back references are called by using `\1` instead of `$1`. Having said that you can try something like the following with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+)/\2\n/g;' file
23 oranges
55 bananas
3 peaches

16 m&m's
5 ju_ju_beans
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i,$(i+1)}' file
23 oranges
55 bananas
3 peaches
16 m&m's
5 ju_ju_beans
```

Comment: +1 You just beat me to it! :)  I like this approach better as it avoids using regex.

Comment: The is counting on the order of the fields rather than a specific regex match of `\d+\s\S+`.

Comment: @dawg Both way give desired result.  This is as safe approach as regex match.

Comment: I am indeed looking for a regex. Do you know how to use a regex in `awk` for multiple key, value pairs on a line described by a regex?

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, we may delete empty lines after the solution from @jaypal with `sed '/^$/d'`.

```
sed -r 's/([^[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+)/\2\n/g;' file  | sed '/^$/d'
```

The output's here.

```
23 oranges
55 bananas
3 peaches
16 m&m's
5 ju_ju_beans
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk '{printf "%s", gensub(/([^[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+)/,"\\2\n","g")}' file
23 oranges
55 bananas
3 peaches
16 m&m's
5 ju_ju_beans
```

GNU `awk` supports `\s` but does not support `\D` or `\d`.